# Is there a way to mount a monitor away from a desk?

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

I have a narrow desk (it is not deep, i.e. there is not much space between me and the facing edge) and I have my monitor standing on a shelf behind the desk.

I would like to get rid of the shelf and install the monitor directly on the desk, with a monitor mount.

I do not want the monitor to take up desk space so I would like to have it hanging slightly behind the desk (about 10cm / 4").

**Do such mounts exist?** All the ones I saw could at best position the monitor at the level of the mount (when it comes to depth) - and usually a few cm towards the desk.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one on [Amazon[(https://www.amazon.com/Mount-Articulating-Adjustable-Compatible-Computer/dp/B01F2SAU3G/ref=sxin_14_pa_sp_search_thematic_sspa)

It is described as fully articulated.

[image]

[image]